# boost::asio file sending

Tags: c++, boost-asio

There is a server that response a .png file over http:

```
#include "server.h"
string Server::header(int contentLength)
{
    string h =
    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
    "Content-Length: " + boost::lexical_cast<string>(contentLength) + "\n"
    "Content-Type: image/png;\n"
    "Connection: close\n"
    "\n";
    return h;
}
string Server::readMap(const string &filename)
{
    ifstream file (filename.c_str(), ios::in|ios::binary);
    string reply;
    char buf[512];
    while (file.read(buf, sizeof(buf)).gcount() > 0)
        reply.append(buf, file.gcount());
    return reply;
}
void Server::run(const string &filename, int port)
{
    string data = readMap(filename);
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));
        for (;;)
        {
          tcp::socket socket(io_service);
          acceptor.accept(socket);
          boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(header( data.size() )));
          boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(data));
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        cerr << "exception: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Every time an error happens:

> exception: Connection reset by peer

I can see some part of an image in my browser, and sometimes the image is almost complete, but it never works without the error.

If I use wget it looks like

```
wget http://localhost:8089
--2012-03-07 12:07:19--  http://localhost:8089/
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:8089... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 760032 (742K) [image/png]
Saving to: `index.html'

62% [========================================================>                                   ] 475,136     --.-K/s   in 0.002s  

2012-03-07 12:07:19 (287 MB/s) - Read error at byte 475136/760032 (Connection reset by peer). Retrying.

--2012-03-07 12:07:20--  (try: 2)  http://localhost:8089/
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:8089... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 760032 (742K) [image/png]
Saving to: `index.html'

73% [==================================================================>                         ] 557,056     --.-K/s   in 0.001s  

... many failes and finally

--2012-03-07 12:09:01--  (try: 9)  http://localhost:8089/
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:8089... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 760032 (742K) [image/png]
Saving to: `index.html'

100%[===========================================================================================>] 760,032     --.-K/s   in 0.001s
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several more complete HTTP-implementations in the ASIO-docs, including static file serving. One way to go would be to reuse some of that sample code for your application.

In this particular case, there's an example of how to correctly open and buffer a file at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server/request_handler.cpp

```
  std::ifstream is(full_path.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    ...
  char buf[512];
  while (is.read(buf, sizeof(buf)).gcount() > 0)
    rep.content.append(buf, is.gcount());
```

The docs also has examples for actual asynchronous HTTP-implementations. (I assume you're using boost::asio to eventually make it asynchronous?)

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what could cause this, but it _might_ have something to do with not waiting for the request before starting a reply.

You should probably _at least_ do the line-parsing of the HTTP-protocol, and wait until you receive a double-newline-sequence.

Other than that, I cannot really see anything obvious done wrong, except for the incorrect line-termination (HTTP expects \r\n) but I doubt it's the cause of your problem. I am assuming the file aren't changed during the transfer, of course.

Comment: You were wright! > You should probably at least do the line-parsing of the HTTP-protocol, and wait until you receive a double-newline-sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You should receive and decode the HTTP request first, and only send the content if that was what was requested. Browsers sometimes request other resources as well; they may get upset if you send something unexpected, or if you send it before they've sent the request.

You also seem to have an off-by-one error in the data size - you put `data.size()-1` in the header, and then send all of `data`. Perhaps this is a partial workaround for the bug in `readMap`, where you push an extra character after reaching EOF. You would be better off fixing that, by checking for `eof()` after reading but before pushing the character; or by reading in a less error-prone (and more efficient) manner, such as:

```
std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
          std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), 
          std::back_inserter(data));
```

Also, I don't see any reason to copy the vector into a `string`. `vector` can also be converted to an `asio::buffer`.

Comment: I dont think that's the reason. I just tried to download it with curl  (it doesnt send nothing unexpected to server) 
spe$ curl http://craft.omg-team.org > img.png
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 65 1238k   65  817k    0     0   233k      0  0:00:05  0:00:03  0:00:02  243k
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer (sorry for formatting)

Comment: I have edited the file, fixed reading, but the error is still there

Answer (score 0):

Your way of reading the file is incorrect for a start.

Not simply that reading one character at a time isn't a great idea, but the loop is wrong. You could use `istreambuf_iterator<char>` to input or `read()` with a number of characters with `gcount()` determining when the read is complete.